# NTP authentication failing with opcode 108

Tags: linux, rhel, ntp

I'm trying to get NTP authentication working on a cluster of test servers and a couple clients. I've followed the [instructions](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringAutokeyFourTwoFour) at ntp.org. To be honest, though, I'm not sure they are entirely clear despite the simplicity of it.

My server ntp.conf:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

server tick.usno.navy.mil
server ntp-s1.cise.ufl.edu
server ntp.colby.edu
server navobs1.oar.net
server gnomon.cc.columbia.edu

peer local-ntp.server.1
peer local-ntp.server.2
peer local-ntp.server.3
peer local-ntp.server.4

statistics clockstats cryptostats loopstats peerstats
statsdir /var/lib/ntp/ntpstats/
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
filegen cryptostats file cryptostats type day enable
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable

crypto pw password
keysdir /etc/ntp
```

My client ntp.conf:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1

server local-ntp.server.1
server local-ntp.server.2
server local-ntp.server.3
server local-ntp.server.4
server local-ntp.server.5

statistics clockstats loopstats peerstats
statsdir /var/lib/ntp/ntpstats/
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
filegen cryptostats file cryptostats type day enable
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable

crypto pw password
keysdir /etc/ntp
```

I have generated the key files using `ntp-keygen -T -G -p password`. Based on what I've been able to discern from the documentation, this is GQ is the option that is applicable to my needs.

So far this is all that my cryptostats file is comprised of:

```
57046 24310.958 ntpkey_RSAkey_test-server.1.3631069561 mod 512
57046 24310.962 ntpkey_RSAkey_test-server.1.3631069561 mod 512
57046 24310.962 ntpkey_RSA-SHA1cert_test-server.1.3631069561 0x0 len 351
57046 24310.963 refresh ts 0
57046 24310.963 10.153.156.71 flags 0x410001 host local-ntp.server.1 signature sha1WithRSAEncryption
57046 24310.963 10.153.156.72 flags 0x410001 host local-ntp.server.2 signature sha1WithRSAEncryption
57046 24310.963 10.153.156.73 flags 0x410001 host local-ntp.server.3 signature sha1WithRSAEncryption
57046 24373.954 10.153.156.75 flags 0x410001 host local-ntp.server.5 signature sha1WithRSAEncryption
57046 24374.948 10.153.156.72 cert local-ntp.server.2 0x7 sha1WithRSAEncryption (65) fs 3631069775
57046 24374.948 10.153.156.71 cert local-ntp.server.1 0x7 sha1WithRSAEncryption (65) fs 3631069440
57046 24375.947 10.153.156.73 cert local-ntp.server.3 0x7 sha1WithRSAEncryption (65) fs 3631069957
57046 24437.952 10.153.156.71 error 108 opcode 82030000 ts 3631070838 fs 3631069682
57046 24438.947 10.153.156.72 error 108 opcode 82030000 ts 3631070839 fs 3631070007
57046 24438.948 10.153.156.73 error 108 opcode 82030000 ts 3631070839 fs 3631070292
57046 24564.949 10.153.156.75 cert local-ntp.server.5 0x7 sha1WithRSAEncryption (65) fs 3631070455
57046 24629.948 10.153.156.75 error 108 opcode 82030000 ts 3631071030 fs 3631070936
```

`ntpq -p` output:

```
# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 local-ntp.server.1. .CRYP.          16 u  69m 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 local-ntp.server.2. .CRYP.          16 u  69m 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 local-ntp.server.3. .CRYP.          16 u  76m 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 local-ntp.server.4. 192.5.41.40      2 u  604 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 local-ntp.server.5. .CRYP.          16 u  65m 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

From what I've learned, the `CRYP` entries are indicative of failed authentication. This makes me think that server.4 is the only one working.

What might the problem be? Is there anything I should be looking at beyond the cryptostats entries?